# Shift between WMS Tiles in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms

I use Leaflet to show a WMS Layer via a proxy.php (for authentication). That is working on most WMS Layers. But I have some WMS Sources, which are having a small shift in the tiles. See Overlay Map in the example.

[image: See Shift of Tiles in this Image:]

```js
    var map1  = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 30,
        maxNativeZoom: 18
    });
    

    var map4 = new L.tileLayer.wms("https://entwicklung.firetab.ch/maptest/proxy.php?url=http://geoshop.kommunalportal.ch/SWMS?", {
        layers: 'lk_wms_wasser',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        maxZoom:30
    });

    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([47.549904, 9.152927], 18);
    
    var baseMaps = {
        "map1": map1
        
    };
    
    var overlayMaps = {
        "map4": map4
    };
    
    L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

    map1.addTo(map);
    map4.addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div>
```

Comment: if i add the WMS Source in QGIS, there is no Shift.

Comment: Does anybody have a idea, what the problem is?

Comment: Sometimes it happens if external map server has projection different from EPSG:3857.